# lombok 1.16.4 with maven (jdk7) not working

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I am using the @Data annotation, but compiler doesn't see the get/set methods.
pom.xml is fine and lombok is in the classpath for 'mvn compile' command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by upping maven-compiler-plugin version to 3.1